# How to get variable columnID

Tags: reactjs

I have created the delete button

[image]

and I would like to obtain the column variable to be able to delete the item in the correct column, but I don't know how to obtain that data ...I had thought of passing the data as a prop to the function but it doesn't work ...

Thank you very much for your help guys!

link codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-virtual-list-board-forked-ghxw4?file=/src/index.js

```
function Item({ provided, item, style, isDragging, column }) {
  return (
    <div
      {...provided.draggableProps}
      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
      ref={provided.innerRef}
      style={getStyle({
        draggableStyle: provided.draggableProps.style,
        virtualStyle: style,
        isDragging
      })}
      className={`item ${isDragging ? "is-dragging" : ""}`}
    >
      {item.text}
      <button onClick={() => console.log("column", column)}> Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `column.items` in the `itemData` prop, you can pass `column`. You can now access the `column` data inside the `Row` component via the `data` prop which you can then pass to the `Item` component.

```
<FixedSizeList {...props} itemData={column}>
  {Row}
</FixedSizeList>
```

```
const Row = React.memo(function Row(props) {
  const { data: column, index, style } = props
  const { items } = column
  const item = items[index]
  if (!item) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <Draggable draggableId={item.id} index={index} key={item.id}>
      {(provided) => (
        <Item provided={provided} item={item} style={style} column={column} />
      )}
    </Draggable>
  )
}, areEqual)
```

[image: Edit virtual-list-board]

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help. A cordial greeting.